# Python: using where condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is it possible to compute the following using `single where` condition in Python. I'm unable to do that.

```
x = np.arange(10)
```

*If an element of x is smaller than 3, replace it with 3. And if an element of x is bigger than 7, replace it with 7.*

My attempt is as follows, however I'm wondering if it could be done in a single line of code

`x= np.where(x<3 ,3,x)`
`x = np.where(x>7,7,x)`

Sorry, if it seems very basic. But I have just started with numpy

Comment: Simply use `numpy.clip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single line using [numpy.clip()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

```
x = np.arange(10)
np.clip(x, 3, 7)
print(x)

#[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

use [numpy.clip()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

```
In [115]: a = np.arange(10)

In [116]: np.clip(a, 3, 7)
Out[116]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x= np.where(x<3, 3, np.where(x>7, 7, x))
```